# How to get line break char (\n) in Vue 3 slots content?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to migrate a Vue 2 component to Vue 3. The idea is like a "ln2br" ("ln2p" actually) for Vue.

So...

```html
<my-linebreaker>
  This is the line 1.
  This is the line 2.
  This is the line 3.
</my-linebreaker>
```

Should render:

```html
<div>
  <p>  This is the line 1.</p>
  <p>  This is the line 2.</p>
  <p>  This is the line 3.</p>
</div>
```

---

This is the **Vue 2** code of my **working component** `MyLinebreaker.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-for="(line, index) in lines" :key="index">{{ line }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    lines () {
      const slot = this.$slots.default
      const text = slot ? slot[0].text : ''

      return text.split('\n')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The Slots API had changes in **Vue 3**, so I am trying to rewrite my `lines` computed to:

```html
<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    lines () {
      const slot = this.$slots.default
      const text = slot ? slot()[0].children : ''

      return text.split('\n')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But it is rendering wrong (all lines in one) because `.children` does not contain the `\n` char.

```html
<div>
  <p>  This is the line 1. This is the line 2. This is the line 3.</p>
</div>
```

So, how can I get the text content with `\n` char in **Vue 3**?

Comment: Possible related with https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/1600.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `compilerOptions.whitespace` to `preserve` in Vue, as related [here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/1600).

```js
app.config.compilerOptions.whitespace = 'preserve'
```

See **Vue 3** docs for more details: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#compileroptions-whitespace